# javascript play screencast(), how to get inline video working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, inline

I am working on an existing project (new to me).

It has inline videos and links that look like this (haml):

```
%a#play-video{:href => "#", :onclick => "play_screencast(); return false;"}
```

I can't figure out where the js code is that this is calling.
It's rails so so theres over 20 js files like modernizer, application.jsm etc.
but I can't see where this is defined or how this is being done.

What the best way to figure this out?
I want to play my video inline.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run a search through all the js files?

If you're on Linux/Unix/OSX go to the javascript folder and run:

```
grep play_screencast *
```

That should tell you where it is defined.

You can also go to the rails root folder and do a recursive search through all the files in the project like so:

```
grep -r play_screencast .
```

If you're on Windows just run a normal windows text search with Explorer.